# why kendo mvc combobox send (0 - null) value when using strong type view and every kendo control?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm trying to use mvc kendo ui but i have problem when using with strongly typed view, when submit form kendo control send null or zero value to controller !! anothe html helper control send correct value . i will set code example of my work with combobox .

**Model:**

```
    public class Sys_Branches
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("Companyid")]
        public Sys_Companies Sys_Companies { get; set; }

        public   int Companyid { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name required")]
        public string NameA { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name required")]
        public string NameE { get; set; }


    }
```

**View:**

```
@model  MVC_ERP.Models.Sys_Branches

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Branches";
}

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
            @Html.Label("Company")
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
         @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.Notes).Name("Companyid")

                  .DataTextField("NameE")
                          .DataValueField("id")

                          .DataSource(source => source
                              .Read(read => read
                              .Action("FillCompanies", "Branches")
                              )

                              )
                     )    
        </div>
```

**Controller"**

```
       public ActionResult Index(int? id, string submitButton, Sys_Branches MainTbl)
       {


               //New or edit according id pass if 0 new else edit
               if( ModelState.IsValid)
               {
                if (Insert(MainTbl)) return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = MainTbl.id 
               }
               //Model not valid
               return View(MainTbl);
         }

        public ActionResult FillCompanies([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            Session["MemberShipId"] = 1;
            int MemberShipId =Convert.ToInt32(Session["MemberShipId"]);
            var m =  db.Companies.Where(b => b.MemberShipId == MemberShipId && b.Deleted != true);

            //return Json(m.Select(p => new { Companyid = p.id, NameE = p.NameE }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            return Json(  m.AsQueryable(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Dropdown is binded from "Notes" property, and Name is "Companyid".
Your class "Sys_Branches" does not contain "Notes" property.

Use the following code :

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.Companyid).Name("Companyid")
              .DataTextField("NameE")
                      .DataValueField("id")

                      .DataSource(source => source
                          .Read(read => read
                          .Action("FillCompanies", "Branches")
                          )

                          )
                 )
```

On Submit, value will be set in "Companyid" property of your class.